# RedirectMatch неверно составлен

Tags: .htaccess

Есть у меня такой редирект:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*)\?c=([0-9]+) http://test.ru/$1
```

Суть в нем такая. Если адрес такого вида:

```
test.ru/page/page/test.html?c=234
```

то редирект на:

```
test.ru/page/page/test.html
```

Что в нем не так?

Comment: вы просто хотите удалить query ? A зачем?

Comment: @splash58 только если есть один параметр c , если например будет test.ru/page/page/test.html?c=234&c2=323 то не надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

директива `redirectmatch`, так же, как и `redirect`, оперирует только с **путём** запроса (query path).

вам подойдёт, например, такая конструкция (обратите внимание на `?` в `rewriterule` — он обязательно должен быть, чтобы отбросить параметры):

```
rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=[0-9]+$
rewriterule (.*) $1? [R=301,L]
```

проверка:

```
$ wget -S --spider 'http://localhost/index.php?c=123' 2>&1 | grep -i '301\| location'
  HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  Location: http://localhost/index.php
```

Comment: Можете проверить по адресу например http://localhost/dir/index.php?c=123 . у меня не работает

Comment: 1. загрузка модуля `rewrite` включена? 2. `rewrtie`-движок включен? (`rewriteengine on`)? 3. выполнение директив из файлов `.htaccess` разрешено? (`allowoverride all`).

Comment: У меня работает RewriteRule, я их добавлял. И этот тоже работает но не правильно

Comment: в смысле: не так, как вам требуется? уточните, пожалуйста, критерии.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю насчет RedirectMatch, но вот так должно работать

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=\d+$
RewriteRule . /$1?
```

Comment: Нету редиректа. Мне нужен именно он